# esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet (0x00)

Tags: esp8266

he intentado compilar este código al modulo WiFi ESP8266 ESP-01 con arduino Uno pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet (0x00)
```

Ya tengo añadido el enlace json a mis preferencias y tengo instalado la libreia esp8266 community.
Este es mi codigo (el ssid y password lo tengo con la configuracion de mi router).

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char *ssid = "######";
const char *password = "####";
WiFiServer server(80);
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);
   
  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
   
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
   
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
   
  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
 
  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");
    
}
 
void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
   
  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }
   
  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");
   

  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=ON\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 ON<br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=OFF\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 OFF<br>");
  client.println("</html>");
 
  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");
 
}
```

Y este es el error completo:

> Arduino:1.8.13 (Windows 10), Tarjeta:"Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), dtr (aka nodemcu), 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 1MB (FS:64KB OTA:~470KB), 2, nonos-sdk 2.2.1+100 (190703), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
>
> Executable segment sizes:
>
> IROM   : 244564          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR)
>
> IRAM   : 26892   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...)
>
> DATA   : 1260  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP
>
> RODATA : 1080  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP
>
> BSS    : 25008 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP
>
> El Sketch usa 273796 bytes (28%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El máximo es 958448 bytes.
>
> Las variables Globales usan 27348 bytes (33%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 54572 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 81920 bytes.
>
> esptool.py v2.8
>
> Serial port COM3
>
> Connecting........*****.....*****.....*****.....*****.....*****.....*****....._____
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\PABLO RUIZ\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 65, in
>
> esptool.main(cmdline)
>
> File "C:/Users/PABLO RUIZ/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main
>
> esp.connect(args.before)
>
> File "C:/Users/PABLO RUIZ/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect
>
> raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
>
> esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet (0x00)
>
> esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Invalid head of packet (0x00)
>
> Este informe podría contener más información con
> "Mostrar salida detallada durante la compilación"
> opción habilitada en Archivo -> Preferencias.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a [comentarios](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/7125) de otros usuarios, es un lío externo, sea de tu IDE o de la placa misma.

Prueba revisando si el reset pin está conectado a tierra -aterrizado- en la board Arduino. Es lo que usa el arduino para saber que debe pasar el código.

Parece importante que revises también la configuración de los pines

```
GND -> GND
TX -> TX
RX -> RX
VCC -> VC
```